# WinForm Chart Color

Tags: c#, windows, forms, chat

I'm trying to find how to change color for chart body lines in Windows Form.
Any help would be appreciated.
[image: ‏]

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want to change. If you mean the *external* (Top/Right) lines, those are set with `chart1.ChartAreas[0].BorderColor`, also setting `chart1.ChartAreas[0].BorderDashStyle` to something that is not `ChartDashStyle.NotSet`. Otherwise, post a better description of the chart parts/details you want to customize.

Comment: Is that a border or what?? Anyway it is not the ugliest part of the chart..